# Design Patterns - DTO, POCO, MODEL

Tags: design-pattern, poco

Qual a diferença de DTO, POCO, MODEL?
Porque estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com separação em camadas, DAL, BLL e UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## POCO = *Plain Old Class Object*

**POCO** é derivado de **POJO**. [O termo foi inventado pelo Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html). O POCO (normalmente) segue os preceitos clássicos da programação orientada a objetos, como estado e comportamento. Por exemplo:

```
classe Porta 
{
    // Estado
    booleano Aberta;

    // Comportamentos
    metodo Fechar() 
    {
        Aberta = falso;
    }

    metodo Abrir() 
    {
        Aberta = verdadeiro;
    }
}
```

## DTO = *Data Transfer Object*

**DTO** seria um *objeto de transferência de dados*, em português. Ele seria mais a representação de um modelo de dados, portanto, contendo apenas "estados", sem comportamentos.

```
classe Porta 
{
    // Estado
    booleano Aberta;
}

// Não existe aqui "Abrir" ou "Fechar": aqui se manipula diretamente os valores.
minhaPorta = nova Porta();
minhaPorta.Aberta = falso;
minhaPorta.Aberta = verdadeiro;
```

## Model

Um **Model**, ou *modelo*, já é um tanto auto-explicativo: ele representa um modelo de dados de alguma entidade sobre a qual se deseja descrever, mas não apenas isso: ele descreve também as relações entre outras entidades. Quanto mais incrementado é o *Model* na questão da descrição tecnológica dele, mais ele se aproxima de um *DTO* do que de um *POCO*.

Os *frameworks* normalmente divergem sobre o que um *Model* se aproxima. Em alguns casos, como Django e Ruby on Rails, o *Model* se aproxima de um *POCO*. Em outros, como o ASP.NET MVC e o Hibernate, se aproxima de um *DTO*.

Em todo caso, o *Model* é o que menos serve para uma arquitetura de três camadas (conforme proposta na pergunta) justamente porque é um padrão de design voltado para o funcionamento de um *framework* MVC, em que os objetos e as relações entre eles têm uma pegada muito mais tecnológica que numa arquitetura puramente orientada a objetos. Curiosamente, a arquitetura em 3 camadas se aproxima mais da abordagem puramente orientada a objetos que o MVC.