# Como estender POCOs do Entity Framework encapsulando as regras de negócio?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, arquitetura-de-software, code-first

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema 3 camadas. Minha intenção inicial era expôr as entidades da camada de negócios para serem usadas no repositório (EF code first).

Quero fazer isso para que eu possa persistir (na memória) as entidades, para que fiquem gerenciadas pelo `DbContext` e não precisar buscar as mesmas entidades em cada parte de um *request*, o que não seria possível se usasse DTOs.

> Exemplo: criar um documento. Para tanto, o usuário precisa ter permissão para criar documentos, e o documento tem uma relação com o usuário criador.
>
> Assim, ao tratar esse caso, eu precisaria primeiro verificar as permissões do usuário, buscando isso no banco de dados. Depois, precisaria usar o mesmo usuário na criação do glossário.

(*Exemplo simplificado, somente para ilustrar a situação)

No exemplo acima, se eu usar DTOs entre o repositório e a camada de negócios, cada trip deverá ser isolada, e eu precisaria buscar o usuário duas vezes (ou dar attach e mudar o status, mas o ponto não é esse).

Então, eu queria manter as entidades na camada de negócios, sem usar DTOs. Mas também quero encapsular as funcionalidades da BL. Meu plano inicial era usar, na camada de negócios, classes herdadas das entidades usadas pelo `DbContext`.

Claro que isso não funcionaria. Então fico sem saber como fazer. Posso usar métodos de extensão, mas minhas entidades são mais complexas que isso, e teriam várias propriedades a mais além de métodos (daí minha intenção de isolar essa complexidade da camada de negócios).

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 8):

Essa pergunta é uma coleção de problemas. Mesmo que você não a considere, vou utilizar ela como um guia do que não fazer numa aplicação ASP.NET MVC.

> Estou desenvolvendo um sistema ASP.NET MVC 3 camadas. Minha intenção inicial era expôr modelos da camada de negócios para serem usadas no repositório (EF code first).

Isto é alarmante de ler. [Veja quantas vezes já tive que falar que não se implementa repositório em cima de Entity Framework, que já é um repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio).

Outra coisa é essa "exposição de modelos da camada de negócios". No ASP.NET MVC, o que são expostos são *Controllers*, que devolvem vários tipos de formatos, como HTML, XML e JSON.

> Quero fazer isso para que eu possa persistir (na memória) as entidades, para que fiquem gerenciadas pelo `DbContext` e não precisar buscar as mesmas entidades em cada parte de um *request*, o que não seria possível se usasse DTOs.
>
> Exemplo: criar um documento. Para tanto, o usuário precisa ter permissão para criar documentos, e o documento tem uma relação com o usuário criador.
>
> Assim, ao tratar esse caso, eu precisaria primeiro verificar as permissões do usuário, buscando isso no banco de dados. Depois, precisaria usar o mesmo usuário na criação do glossário.

Muito provavelmente você não compreende como funciona um `DbContext`. A cada requisição ele é renovado, justamente porque a ideia de persistir em memória é péssima e pode causar conflitos. Cada requisição possui o seu `DbContext`, e nem por isso a ideia de ir ao banco a cada requisição é ruim.

Muito provavelmente você não conhece o conceito de filtros, que é uma das grandes vantagens do MVC. As permissões são vistas **a nível de aplicação**, e não a nível de banco. [Aqui explico várias maneiras de fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorizeattribute). No seu caso, seria um filtro mais específico que funcionaria juntamente com o contexto.

Ainda, se você quer algo mais rápido que o banco, [uma *cache* chave-valor como o Redis](http://redis.io/) é mais adequada.

> Então, eu queria manter as entidades na camada de negócios, sem usar DTOs. Mas também quero encapsular as funcionalidades da BL. Meu plano inicial era usar, na camada de negócios, classes herdadas das entidades usadas pelo `DbContext`.
>
> Claro que isso não funcionaria. Então fico sem saber como fazer. Posso usar métodos de extensão, mas meus modelos são mais complexos que isso, e teriam várias propriedades a mais além de métodos (daí minha intenção de isolar essa complexidade da camada de negócios).

Um *Model* não é uma DTO. Não é uma entidade anêmica. Você pode escrever comportamentos e validações para o *Model*. Não há necessidade dessa separação. O ganho é zero.

Por fim, você incorre em todas as práticas perfeitamente evitáveis do ASP.NET MVC, possivelmente por querer que ele se comporte como um DDD:

- Implementar um repositório em cima de Entity Framework (que já é um repositório);
- Implementar uma camada de negócio em um *framework* que possui um padrão de design semelhante (*Controller*);
- Tratar *Model* como um POCO ou como DTO ([e que não são nem uma coisa nem outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76919/design-patterns-dto-poco-model/76934#76934));
- Complicar o que não precisa ser complicado.

Sugiro você repensar todo este projeto ou abandonar o ASP.NET MVC de vez. Creio que ele vá mais te atrapalhar que ajudar.

Comment: +1 pelo `Implementar um repositório em cima de Entity Framework (que já é um repositório);`, cheguei até a questionar isto em uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern) minha, mas confesso que a resposta não me convenceu muito.

Comment: @TobyMosque Valeu por indicar. Posso te dar outra resposta lá, se quiser.

Comment: Uma nova opinião a respeito é sempre bem  vindo

Comment: Primeiro, estou usando ASP.NET MVC, mas posso e vou usar outros front ends. Segundo, Não quero persistir as entidades além de um request, queria persistir dentro de uma request. Finalmente, talvez esteja errado, mas minhas relações serão bastante complexas no lado do BD, e vou precisar de attach complexos, e quero, preciso delegar isso para uma camada a parte (repositório).

Comment: Não _discordo_ de nada que disse, só não sei como se aplica à pergunta *Como estender POCOs do Entity Framework encapsulando as regras de negócio?*, e provavelmente foi por falta de clareza na pergunta.

Comment: Bom, então boa sorte com sua implementação. Cabe a mim apenas apontar o que está errado. De qualquer forma, vou usar essa questão algumas vezes, porque ela sintetiza uma porção de problemas das aplicações ASP.NET MVC modernas que vejo por aí.

Comment: Não, eu nem quis responder de fato sua pergunta, porque ela não tem nem pé nem cabeça. A ideia é usá-la para outros fins didáticos. Fique à vontade para ser contra ela.

Comment: Não vejo como ASP.NET MVC influencia na arquitetura das outras camadas. Como uma questão acerca de como arquitetar a relação entre BL e Repositório pode mostrar um erro comum em uma tecnologia de apresentação? Imagine a mesma pergunta para um aplicativo console que seja. Não importa a apresentação.

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples: membros `internal`.

Expondo os modelos ou entidades do domínio para serem usadas pelo repositório (e pela camada de apresentação quando couber), e expondo os membros exclusivos à lógica de negócios como `internal`, só ficando visíveis dentro da lógica de negócios.

Comment: Olá! Se eu entendi bem sua resposta (e também sua pergunta), tudo o que você queria era saber sobre visibilidade ou encapsulamento de membros de classes. Nesse caso, sua pergunta está desnecessariamente complexa, pois todos aqueles detalhes sobre armazenar entidades em memória, permissões e outros são irrelevantes para a resposta. Essa confusão provavelmente deu margem à outra resposta. Minha sugestão é que você edite sua pergunta deixando apenas as informações relevantes ao seu problema de visibilidade. Seria interessante ainda incluir um treco de código para exemplificar o que está dizendo.

Comment: @utluiz Depois de achar um jeito de fazer, realmente toda parte da pergunta que não alimenta a resposta poderia ser eliminada. Mas esperava encontrar _outros_ meios de fazer, talvez mais certo. A minha resposta responde, mas é o único jeito? O melhor jeito?