# ASP.NET MVC e DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Estou tentando usar DDD e Fluent Api, em uma aplicação teste. Me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho um cadastro de produtos (nesse caso tinta), ao incluir um novo produto eu coloquei dropdownlist´s, para forçar o cadastro correto e padronizado, ex: Branco RAL 9003 LI BR PO, essas siglas e a cor vem de dropdownlist´s, e quero salvar em um campo "descrição", pois na página index vou mostrar somente essa descrição.

Eu pensei em fazer assim: colocar o campo descrição como readonly e conforme for selecionando os itens das dropdownlist´s ele vai preenchendo o campo descrição, usando javascripts, porém acho que irá ferir a regra de DDD.

Será que está correto fazer assim ou existe outra forma melhor? Se existir outra forma mais correta, qual seria? Qual camada colocaria essa rotina?

Comment: Leia isto antes, por favor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78716/como-estender-pocos-do-entity-framework-encapsulando-as-regras-de-neg%C3%B3cio

Comment: Então você tem um cadastro de tintas e um cadastro de cores e vai criar um novo produto a partir da combinação destes dois cadastros, sendo que o novo produto terá um atributo "descrição" concatenando o nome dos dois itens selecionados? A coisa esquisita que vejo aí são as informações replicadas (redundância). Se a redundância não for problema e se para a entidade Produto o que vale é que foi informada uma descrição; o fato de esta descrição ter sido facilitada para o usuário não é um problema.

Comment: Agora, se você tem no Produto o campo "descrição" só para facilitar a exibição de uma informação que é obtida a partir de outros atributos do produto (tinta e cor), então está errado. Você deveria cuidar destes detalhes de exibição na hora de exibir em vez de redundar informações na entidade. Outra coisa: **onde DDD entra nessa história?**

Comment: Caffé, boa noite! Então o problema é o seguinte, vamos dar um exemplo de tinta Branca Lisa Brilhante Poliéster, eu quero forçar uma padronização pois no cadastro antigo que tem está cadastrado somente Tinta Branca. E o resto das informações, acredito que eu fazendo assim consigo forçar um cadastro padronizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o padrão DDD, regras de negócio sempre ficam na camada de Domínio.

"Domínio – representa os conceitos, regras e lógicas de negócio. Todo o foco de DDD está nessa camada. Nosso trabalho, daqui para frente, será aperfeiçoar e compreender profundamente essa parte." [(DANIEL CUKIER)](http://www.agileandart.com/2010/07/16/ddd-introducao-a-domain-driven-design/)

Portando você tem que avaliar, essa regra da descrição é uma regra de negócio, caso o usuário altere essa descrição pelo Html e a aplicação acabar gravando essa informação isso irá afetar o sistema ?

Eu faria da seguinte forma, criaria uma método na minha camada de Domínio que recebe as informações necessárias para montar a descrição. Ao salvar a informação o seu método salvar chamará novamente o método para criar a descrição. Assim você garante que a descrição do seu produto sempre terá o mesmo padrão.