# Entendendo o Conceito DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ddd

Bom,

Estou começando uma nova aplicação, relativamente simples, e estou querendo estruturá-la no conceito DDD.

Li muito na internet, vi muitos exemplos e significados, mas gostaria de saber de maneira mais simples.

Dada a seguinte estrutura (a padrão que mais encontrei na internet):

- "Projeto".Application: Class Library aonde ficam meus aquivos de
  persistência/repositório e interface;
- "Projeto".Domain: Class Library aonde se encontram meus
  "Models/Entities";
- "Projeto".Infra.Data: Class Library responsável pelo mapeamento das
  models (mapping/fluentAPI);
- "Projeto".MVC: Projeto MVC padrão, porém sem as Models e
  Repositórios diretamente explícitos;

**Essa estrutura está mesmo correta?** Pois pretendo seguir com ela para meus próximos projetos e reformular alguns que já estão implantados.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78716/como-estender-pocos-do-entity-framework-encapsulando-as-regras-de-neg%c3%b3cio/80674?s=2|0.7859#80674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta correta é: depende. Sua arquitetura deve ser emergente, isto é, seus requisitos devem guiar a arquitetura.

Essa organização de projetos está correta? R: Sim.

No entanto, quais são seus requisitos? Altíssima performance? Se a resposta for afirmativa, essa separação de projetos poderá afetar a performance, embora favoreça a manutenção / organização.

Eu sugiro algo mais simples, e se necessário, você refatora.

Comment: Entendi sim. Na realidade prioriza sim a performance, mas nada ao estilo "real time". Só um ponto: Quando você fala em "Eu sugiro algo mais simples", você se refere ao MVC "nu e cru", como ele vem, tudo separado dentro de um único Project?

Comment: para projetos pequenos não teria problema, mas imagino que não seja este o caso ... eu geralmente uso o mvc como apresentação, tenho um class library para regras de negocio e outro para acesso a dados...

Comment: aproveitando, adquira o livro do Dino Esposito - Enterprise .NET Applications Version 2 ... excelente livro ;)