# Entity Framework, duvidas com a estrutura da solução (app.config e package.config)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

Iniciei uma solução com Entity Framework code-first.
Na estrutura da solução, eu separei os domínios dos demais arquivos do EF (context, etc.). Ou seja, os domínios ficaram em um projeto separado.
Porém, para que eu pudesse fazer uso dos data anotations do EF, eu precisei referenciar o EF no projeto dos domínios também. Dessa forma, eu tenho o EF referenciado em dois lugares, no projeto dos domínios e no projeto onde fica os demais arquivos do EF, assim acabo tendo dois arquivos `app.config` e dois `package.config`.
É necessário que cada projeto que referencie o EF tenha seus próprios arquivos `app.confg` e `package.config`?

[image: MeuProjetoImagem1]
[image: MeuProjetoImagem2]

Answer (score 2):

Algumas observações antes da resposta:

1. O Entity Framework já é um ORM. Você não precisa criar um projeto para envelopar isso;
2. Você não precisa separar o domínio da camada ORM. O correto é o contexto e as entidades ficarem no mesmo projeto;
3. Você está colocando um nível desnecessário de complexidade no seu projeto. Um *Model* não é um DTO porque não é anêmico. A meu ver, você está incorrendo [nos mesmos erros desta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78716/como-estender-pocos-do-entity-framework-encapsulando-as-regras-de-neg%C3%B3cio);
4. Em `DataTransferObjects` (que, pelas boas práticas, deve ser descartado da sua solução), o correto seria agrupar suas entidades pelo *namespace* através de um diretório.

Vamos à resposta:

> É necessário que cada projeto que referencie o EF tenha seus próprios arquivos `app.config` e `package.config`?

Sim, é. Explico:

O `app.config` indica ao Entity Framework quais são os provedores de dados que serão usados. Se há um contexto na camada, e a camada funciona independentemente do projeto Web, a configuração é necessária.

Para provar isso, experimente executar uma migração usando como projeto inicial sua camada de domínio isolada.

O `package.config` indica ao NuGet o que você está usando de dependência externa na sua *Class Library*. Cada componente da solução possui seu próprio `packages.config`. Um exemplo disso é que você não usará dependências Web em uma *Class Library* de domínio, e não usará EF em um projeto Web que não tem descritivo algum de acesso a dados.

Comment: Sei..
Encontrei, alguns exemplos onde os autores separavam os domínios do contexto.
Eu entrei em .net a algumas semanas, não estou familiarizado com as melhores praticas de organização do projeto.
Essa solução trata-se de uma solução Desktop/WPF, mas eu pretendo aplicar os conceitos MVC.
Eu já havia observado que o nome `DataTransferObject` não estava adequado.

Comment: Conheço bem esses autores. A intenção é boa, mas não funciona. Tem uma série de respostas aqui no site que mostro que isso é uma péssima ideia. Se for do seu interesse, posso mandar os links.

Comment: Sim, será útil.

Comment: [Aqui explico porque é péssima a prática de encapsular EF num repositório](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696). [Aqui explico porque um *Model* não é um DTO e qual a diferença entre eles](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76919/design-patterns-dto-poco-model/76934#76934).